# How to run push notifications loop in the background laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification, background-process

Now I need to send FCM push notifications to all my users on every record add, but it's take so much time to loop through them all, how to make the loop work in the background?

I'm using brozot/Laravel-FCM package

Comment: If it's take much time then use queue to push all notification.

Answer (score 0):

You might be triggering an event for push notification. so, while triggering an event for push notification you can push the notifications to queue. This queue is basically implemented in class declared in Listeners folder. example:

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\EventName;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\FcmAdapter; 

class NotificationClassName implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  EventName  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(EventName $event)
    {
       // code for sending FCM notification. 
    }
}
```

***implements ShouldQueue*** is the way to implement queue.